# How do I use the Savon gem to make a currency converter in a Rails application?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, savon

I am trying to integrate a currency converter into my Ruby on Rails application using the Savon gem to fetch data from http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx?WSDL.
I was following the tutorial at http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/How-to-use-Savon-in-Ruby-on-Rails-Application-2367.php but I am not able to send a request when I click the submit button.
I have exactly followed what the tutorial is saying.
this is my code.

i have one controller,

---

```
class ConverterController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def show
  end

  def create
    # creating a object of the CurrencyConverter model
    currency = CurrencyConverter.new(params[:fromCurrency],params[:toCurrency])
    render :json => currency.result
  end
end
```

---

model:

---

```
class CurrencyConverter < ActiveRecord::Base
  require 'savon'
    attr_reader :result
  # purpose :  for initializing the object of currency converter
  # params : fromCurrecny(unit),toCurrency(unit)
  # return : none

  def initialize(fromCurrency , toCurrency)
    # creating a client from the wsdl schema 
    client = Savon::Client.new("http://webservicex.net/currencyconvertor.asmx?wsdl")
    # calling the api with fromCurrecny and toCurrency unit

    response = client.request :web, :conversion_rate, body: {
                       "FromCurrency" =>     fromCurrency , "ToCurrency" => toCurrency
                      }

    #checking for success of api call
    if response.success?
      data = response.to_array(:conversion_rate_response).first
      if data
        # setting convertion rate to result   
        @result = data[:conversion_rate_result]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

---

my view in index.html.erb

---

```
<h1>Public#index</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/public/index.html.erb</p>

<div id="welcome">

    <label> From Currency Unit</label>
     <select name="from_currency" id="from_currency">
         <option value="">Select Currency</option>
        <option value="GBP">British Pound</option>
        <option value="INR">Indian Rupee</option>
        <option value="PKR">Pakistani Rupee</option>
        <option value="SGD">Singapore Dollar</option>
        <option value="ZAR">South African Rand</option>
        <option value="USD">U.S. Dollar</option>
    </select>
 <input type="text" id="from_amount" placeholder="Enter From Curreny Amount"/>
 <br>

 <label> To Currency Unit</label>
 <select name="to_currency" id="to_currency">
        <option value="">Select Currency</option>
        <option value="GBP">British Pound</option>
        <option value="INR">Indian Rupee</option>
        <option value="PKR">Pakistani Rupee</option>
        <option value="SGD">Singapore Dollar</option>
        <option value="ZAR">South African Rand</option>
        <option value="USD">U.S. Dollar</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" readonly id="to_amount" placeholder="to Curreny Amount"/>
  <br>
  <input type="button" class="btn" id="get_conversion_rate" value="Get Conversion">
```

---

i am using a ajax call for submitting this fromCurrency And toCurrency unit. i placed the code under /assets/javascripts/CurrencyConverter.js
then added the line <% javascript_include_tag :all %> in application.html.erb file to include them
The code for it is

---

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var rate = 0.0;
        var fromCurrency = $("#from_currency");
        var toCurrency= $("#to_currency");
        var fromAmount = $("#from_amount");
        var toAmount = $("#to_amount");
        var  button = $('#get_conversion_rate');

        var getConversionRate = function(){
            $.post('/publics',{
                fromCurrency : fromCurrency.val(),
                toCurrency : toCurrency.val()
              },function(data) {
                rate = data;
                toAmount.val(fromAmount.val()*rate);
           });
        };

        var initializer = function(){
            button.click(getConversionRate);
         };
        initializer();
});
```

---

please help.

Comment: You need to show us enough of your code and form to duplicate the problem. As is, we have no idea if you correctly followed the tutorial without making any mistakes. Are there any errors or messages returned? "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See http://SSCCE.org for guidance."

Comment: i have edited my question and added the code, i hope now it is clear. any question?

Comment: anybody with ideas?? thanks, Benjamin

Comment: What errors do you get in the log in rails? Do you get an error in the JavaScript console of your browser when you click the button? Have you mapped the route `/publics` (in your JavaScript) to your Converter controller?

Comment: did you read the answer? was it useful? If you don't react ppl won't bother to help you.

Comment: yea i did, it worked but the requirements were changed to google currency API. i appreciate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go. The smallest possible example, works for Savon v2.x:

```
require 'savon'

c=Savon.client(wsdl: "http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx?WSDL")

r=c.call(:conversion_rate,
         message: {'FromCurrency' => 'EUR', 'ToCurrency' => 'CAD'})

print r.to_hash[:conversion_rate_response][:conversion_rate_result]
```

Comment: i upvoted!too bad the requirements were changed to using Google currency API. thanks alot

Comment: thanks. I didn't know about the Google calls. That was good new information.